# I'm trying out Rust, but following the book I've encountered some problems

Tags: rust

```rs
        let mut adivinado = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut adivinado)
        .expect("Couldn't read Input.");

        let adivinado: u32 = adivinado.trim().parse()
        .expect("NAN.");
```

When I build it, it doesn't complain, but when I input a char that isn't a number, instead of outputting: "NAN.", it says "thread 'main' panicked at 'No es un número.: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }'".
I originally had

```rs
        .{
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };
```

Instead of the except, but when doing so it outputs:

```rs
error: unexpected token: `{`
  --> src\main.rs:22:10
   |
22 |         .{
   |          ^

error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `else`, or an operator, found `{`
  --> src\main.rs:22:10
   |
22 |         .{
   |          ^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `else`, or an operator
```

Maybe it's some sort of near miss of formating, but I can't figure it out after tinkering arround with it for some time and searching a bit.

Comment: You have a dot there? Was it supposed to be `match`?

Comment: If you print the string before parsing it, what does it contain?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman When I used match it outputs a large error list that I'll list in the next response, responding to the second coment, it just reprints like normal, if the input is 4, 4, if the input is a, a:
`¡Adivina el número!
Introduce tu número:
4
4

Adivinaste el número: 4
¡Muy pequeño!
Introduce tu número:   
a
a

thread 'main' panicked at 'No es un número.: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }'`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FunzZ4gY

Comment: It needs to be something like `match adivinado.trim().parse() { ... }`. Anyway, I don't really understand the answer to my question. If you put `dbg!(&adivinado)` before the `parse()` call, what does it print? `4, 4`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman THat Match trick seems to have done it, Thank you, although I don't really understand what the match does or why to espect didn't work, Either way, It now seems to work, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your error doesn't match your code, and that it works as intended.

When I run:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut adivinado = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut adivinado)
        .expect("Couldn't read Input.");

    let adivinado: u32 = adivinado.trim().parse().expect("NAN.");
}
```

And run it, but enter a non-number:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'NAN.: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:10:51
```

You can clearly see the `NAN.` followed by a `ParseIntError`. In your example the error says `No es un número.`, followed by a `ParseIntError`.

Therefore I suspect that your original code said `.expect("No es un número.")`, and the error you show does not belong to the code you posted.

So everything is expected, `expect` raises a panic with the given text combined with the error message.

Comment: You are correct in everything stated, my error was from before I translated my code's comments to english, "No es un número." is essencially the same as NAN. Either way, you are right, this is expected behavior, how could I have it write the "NAN.", kind of as a log, but not have it stop when it panics?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that, how should it continue? The next step in your code is to write the `u32` into `adivinado`, what should it write there if it wasn't able to parse the number?

Comment: My idea was for it to print a "that's incorrect" and an error code + explication or whatever it's format is; and after that, discard the operation of writting a string or whatever into a u32 and try again, idk if that makes sense in this context or I'm missunderstanding the posibilities or the usage of some of this parts

Comment: Many things make sense, you just have to program them ;)
You don't have to use `expect`; actually, using `expect` is the worst way to code this, it's only recommended in prototyping. In actual code, [handle the error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) instead. If you are on it, I recommend [reading the entire book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).